# Xml root node not closed

Tags: c#, xml, root, stack-overflow

I'm using xmlwriter to create an xml document. The xml document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ExceptionsList />
```

How can i prevent the /> and appropriately end the root node?

Because of this, i can't append anything to the root node.

My code for creating the xml file looks like this:

```
string formatDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy");

XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlfileName, Encoding.UTF8);

xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlWriter.Indentation = 3;
xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ExceptionsList"); // ExceptionsList (Root) Element

xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // End of ExceptionsList (Root) Element

xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();

xmlWriter.Flush();
xmlWriter.Close();
```

And I append to the root node like this:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlFileName);
XElement root = xml.Root;

root.Add(new XElement("Exception",
    new XElement("Exception Type", exceptionType),
    new XElement("Exception Message", exceptionMessage),
        new XElement("InnerException", innerException),
    new XElement("Comment", comment)));

xml.Save(xmlFileName);
```

This gives me a stackoverflow at runtime error too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused... why do you say that it isn't appropriately closed? It looks closed to me...

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean. Where is the stack overflow happening? Why would you not want your root element to be closed? Why would you expect XmlWriter to produce invalid output?

Comment: What's stopping you putting the second code fragment (or a suitable call) between the ExceptionList's start and end element calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is right, and you don't need to change how your `ExceptionsList` element is closed.

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ExceptionsList"); // ExceptionsList (Root) Element

xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Exception"); // An Exception element
xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

xmlWriter.WriteEndElement(); // End of ExceptionsList (Root) Element
```

In your second snippet, you need to remove those white spaces from element name, as XML specification forbid that and add your elements into your `XDocument` instance, like this:

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument();
xml.Add(new XElement("Exception",
    new XElement("ExceptionType", "Exception"),
    new XElement("ExceptionMessage", 
        new XElement("InnerException", "innerException")),
    new XComment("some comment")));

xml.Save("sample2.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here:

```
    new XElement("Exception Type", exceptionType),
     new XElement("Exception Message", exceptionMessage),
```

Neither `Exception Type` nor `Exception Mesage` is a valid name for an xml element. Then of course, if you use *this* (doomed) method to log the error... stack overflow.

Comment: Yes that's what caused the stackoverflow. I got ride of it. TBH, i never used spaces in xml tags. I don't know why i did this time :o
Thanks for your comment!